# Installing Ubuntu after hard-drive re-formating: The partitioner won't work

Tags: ubuntu, installation, multi-boot

When I get to the part where you partition your disk, no disks are shown. How do I fix this? Do I need to shrink one of my partitions so I have some free (unallocated) space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unmount all partitions before running the partitioner

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: the partitions should appear on the desktop,right click on them,then choose "unmount",do this to all the drives you see on the desktop,then start the partitioner

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Ubuntu using the alternate install CD, http://releases.ubuntu.com/9.04/